# How can I force my laptop to display in 1366x768?

Tags: laptop, resolution

I want to plug my HP TouchSmart tx2 TabletPC on my TV monitor. It's suppose to support a 1366x768 resolution, but Win7/ATI drivers won't allow me to go higher than 1024x768, even though it's capable of 1680x1050 on other monitors.

How can I tell the video drivers to try 1366x768 (60Hz)?

**Update**: I have Windows 7 with an ATI Radeon HD 3200, with the latest "beta" drivers. I suspect it's rather the TV that is not recognized as "1366x768 capable". Is there a way to force Windows into thinking it is capable?

Comment: which video card are you using?

Comment: Have you downloaded all updates for your video-card?

Comment: What Operating System are you running?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a bit complex (and it costs money), but [PowerStrip](http://entechtaiwan.com/util/ps.shtm) might be able to force your graphics card in to that resolution.

Comment: PowerStrip does exactly what I **thought** I needed. It allowed me to try resolutions like 1360x768 @ 60Hz (vert.). Unfortunately, I finally found information about my TV and its VGA input, and that's where the problem occurs. The maximum supported resolution is 1024x768. I'll mark this as a correct answer, and ask a different question about alternatives (i.e. S-Video or HDMI converters)