# Force screen resolution to its maximum in Windows

Tags: windows, display, resolution, edid

I have a [Samsung SyncMaster SA100 monitor](http://www.samsung.com/levant/consumer/computers-peripherals/monitors/lcd-tv-monitor/LS19A100NS/UF) which I got after my good old CRT failed. The CRT had a maximum supported resolution of 1024x768 and the Samsung has 1366x768. However, when I connect the Samsung monitor, the maximum resolution detected by the PC is 1024x768 (as seen in the `Screen Resolution` window).

Using the information given [here](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/7947-force-dvi-hdmi-resolutions-refresh-rates.html), I changed the EDID to add support for **1360x765** which is what my monitor is currently set to. But the Phoenix EDID Tool doesn't allow me to set the horizontal resolution to any arbitrary value (its either 1360 or 1368 i.e. multiples of 8 only).

Is it possible to set/force the monitor resolution to 1366x768?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I force my laptop to display in 1366x768?](http://superuser.com/questions/6198/how-can-i-force-my-laptop-to-display-in-1366x768)

Comment: Do you have the proper graphics card and display drivers installed? Typically, when your resolution is restricted to less than what your hardware supports, it's because generic display drivers are being used.

Comment: @Gnoupi That question still doesn't answer how to force the resolution to 1366x768

Comment: @Lèsemajesté I updated them before trying what I said above.

Comment: @Manu If the answer is no, you need to install them and the proper resolution should appear in your list of options. If the answer is yes then something is wrong and you need to either re-install the drivers of the monitor or the video card in order for it to show in the list. Basically what Lese is saying is if the drivers are installed properly, then the resolution should appear as an option. Lese doesn't seem to think your drivers are installed correctly.

Comment: @Lèsemajesté Also, my graphics card is an old one (ATI Xpress 200).

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes when switching to a different external monitor Windows doesn't realise it and limits the new monitor to the resolutions the old one supported. I've had this problem myself a couple of times. To remedy it, go to the Screen Resolution control panel and click the Detect button. This should force Windows to redetect the display and its supported resolutions.

If that doesn't work, look around in your graphics driver settings. AMD/ATI Catalyst Control Center should let you manually specify the maximum resolution (and refresh rate) for each monitor.